# ¿Cómo este código puede obtener el factorial?

Tags: javascript

Encontré este código y realmente no logro entenderlo para nada, llevo muchísimo tiempo tratando de entenderle, **lo que hace es sacar el factorial de cualquier número, pero no entiendo cómo lo hace,** habitualmente lo veía como un `ciclo for`, pero esto? que complicado se me hace..

```js
function y(e) {
    return (function (f) {
        return f(f);
    }(function (f) {
        return e(function (x) {
            return f(f)(x);
        });
    }));
}

var factorial = y(function (recur) {
    return function (n) {
        return (n <= 2) 
            ? n 
            : n * recur(n - 1);
    };
});

var num = factorial(6);
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Woh!!!
un poco enrevesado si que es

Comment: A simple vista parece más bien un código ofuscado de una función factorial. La función más común de factorial es esta, o al menos la más sencilla que yo conozco, y que usa recursividad: https://jsfiddle.net/y8dx9qLe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funciones **y,f,e,x,recur**... están demás, la implementación directa es esta

```js
var factorial =  function (n) {
        return (n <= 2) 
            ? n 
            : n * factorial(n - 1);
    };
```

Una forma fácil de entender la solución es tomar un caso particular y seguir paso a paso su ejecución, tomar lápiz y papel siempre es una buena estrategia.

Para obtener el **factorial de 5**, es necesario haber calculado el factorial de 4 que a su vez depende del valor del factorial de 3 y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al factorial de 1 que no necesita ser calculado.

fact(5) = 5*fact(4) = 5*4*fact(3) = 5*4*3*fact(2) = 5*4*3*2*fact(1) = 5*4*3*2*1

[image: pila de llamadas de la función factorial para n = 5]

La recursión aprovecha la **pila de llamadas a función** para *poner en pausa* la ejecución secuencial del programa al encontrar una llamada de función. Una vez que la llamada termina, se reanuda la ejecución para combinar el valor de retorno de la función con el valor actual de n.

Este es otro ejemplo que suma los primeros n números, la implementación es similar, sólo cambia la manera en que se combinan los resultados, en lugar de usar el operador de multiplicación usamos el de suma.

```
var suma =  function (n) {
    return (n <= 1) 
        ? n 
        : n + suma(n - 1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No conozco manera sencilla de tratar de explicar el tema de recursion.
No se si hayas visto la película de "Inception" pero es algo similar.

Es código, métodos que se mandan a llamar en distintos niveles.

Un ejemplo sencillo es una funcion de Fibonacci

```
int fibonacci(int n)
{
   if (n>1){
      return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);  //función recursiva
   }
   else if (n==1) {  // caso base
      return 1;
   }
     else if (n==0){  // caso base
      return 0;
   }
   else{ //error
       System.out.println("Debes ingresar un tamaño mayor o igual a 1");
       return -1; 
   }
}
```

Aquí se puede como el método o function (creo que estas usando javascript) se manda a llamar a si misma con nuevos valores de "n-1" y "n-2". El detalle cuando usas recursion es que tienes que tener bien clara las condiciones de salida. Es decir que tu código no se cicle llamándose a si mismo hasta agotar los recursos.

En el ejemplo las condiciones de salida es cuando "n" sea 1 o 0.

Espero y te ayude mi explicación.

Comment: Las respuestas deben tratan de resolver la pregunta o dar opciones para su solución, revisa por favor [answer], saludos.